# Using "at least"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which usage is correct? if none, please suggest the correct one:

> I have been working in this job for six months at least

OR

> I have been working in this job for at least six months

Comment: **working in this job** is not idiomatic to begin with.

Comment: You would generally work **at** or **on** a job or task although you could work **in this job** if you meant **in this position. Both your examples are correct English. The second one is easier on the ear.